# How to properly open a SSH tunnel for a program and close it afterwards?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tunnel

I want to run a command that needs a SSH tunnel for its operation (opening TCP connections repeatedly). After it exists, the tunnel needs to be closed again. The problems I encountered are:

1. I can run the command in the background immediately, but then I have no reliable way how to be sure the tunnel has been set up:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   set -e
   ssh -N -L lport:server:port host &
   trap "kill $!" EXIT
   sleep 1
   my program that connects to localhost:lport
   ```

   It often happens that opening the tunnel takes longer than 1s. I could also put there more time, but then the user experience isn't very good, and still it's unreliable.
2. I can let SSH background itself when the connection is opened, but then I can't find a reliable way how to kill it afterwards, because I don't know the PID of the background SSH process:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   set -e
   ssh -f -N -L lport:server:port host
   # I'd set up a trap ??? EXIT, but for what?
   my program that connects to localhost:lport
   ```

   Is there a way how to detect the PID of the SSH process?

Or is there another, better way how to solve the task?

Comment: You might be able to use `ssh -o LocalCommand=yourprogram` to launch the progam once the connection has been established (you might also need to set `PermitLocalCommand=yes`). However, as per `man ssh_config`: *"It should not be used for interactive commands."*

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241063/bash-script-to-setup-a-temporary-ssh-tunnel for answers containing Control Socket and ExitOnForwardFailure.